# ifpdf prematurely terminates iffalse

Tags: pdftex, pdf, conditionals, documentation

I have the following minimum code stored inside the `file.dtx` file:

```
% \iffalse
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{file.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
%<*class>
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf\RequirePackage[
  plainpages=false,          % Multiple page numbering support
  pdfpagelabels,             % Generate pdf page labels
  pdftex,                    % PDF Metadata stamping
  pdfcreator={Some string}
]{hyperref}\fi
%</class>
%    \end{macrocode}
% \fi
```

Trying to typeset this code via `latex file.dtx` results in the following error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{macrocode}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.20 %    \end{macrocode}
```

Removing `\fi` from `\ifpdf ... \fi` makes the error go away, but the cls file generated by docstripping the contents of `<*class> ... </class>` then contains an unterminated if.

Is there something I'm doing wrong and is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! My impression is that `\begin{macrocode}` is wrongly placed.

Comment: Thanks you. :-)  Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: The starting `\iffalse` is used to hide the driver code when  the document is loaded with `\DocInput`, the corresponding `\fi` should not be at the end, but after the driver code. What happens is that `ifpdf` is not loaded when you LaTeX the `.dtx` file, so `\ifpdf` is not a conditional and the corresponding `\fi` matches the initial `\iffalse`. An unbalanced `\end{macrocode}` then shows up.

Comment: `hyperref` will work in DVI mode or with XeTeX: is there a reason you don't just load it in all cases?

Comment: Yeah, removing the `pdftex` option, which throws an error in DVI mode, works as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want

```
% \iffalse
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{file.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
%    \end{macrocode}
% \fi
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*class>
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf\RequirePackage[
  plainpages=false,          % Multiple page numbering support
  pdfpagelabels,             % Generate pdf page labels
  pdftex,                    % PDF Metadata stamping
  pdfcreator={Some string}
]{hyperref}\fi
%</class>
%    \end{macrocode}
```

In your original, after the `\DocInput{file.dtx}` the file is read in wuth `%` being ignored, so `\iffalse` was seen. as this is false `%    \begin{macrocode}` is *skipped* and so the code sections are *not* read verbatim. But they are not executed either.

So `\RequirePackage{ifpdf}` is not executed so `\ifpdf` is not defined. in particular it is not an `\if` ... However when you get to `{hyperref}\fi` the `\fi` *is* defined so terminates the `\iffalse` `%` is still ignored so `\end{macrocode}` is executed and generates the error you state.

As egreg comments the first `macrocode` environment is always either commented out with `%` or skipped with `\iffalse` so doesn't actually do anything, but it may simplify editing if all code sections are so marked, and it doesn't do any harm.

Comment: But the first `macrocode` environment does nothing.

Comment: @egreg it doesn't do harm, that is something.

Comment: Running `latex` on your code typesets the `<*class> ... </class>` part as verbatim. But what if I don't want to typeset it at all? (That's the reason it was wrapped in the `\iffalse`.)

Comment: @Witiko add `\usepackage{ifpdf}` to your driver document where you have babel, then `\ifpdf` will be defined and so can be skipped with `\iffalse...\fi`